# Выбрать в селект значение

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<option
     v-if="position.supplier"
     v-for="supplier in suppliers"
     :value="supplier.id"
     :selected="supplier.id === position.supplier.id">{{ supplier.name }}
</option>
```

Подскажите, у меня сейчас выбирается если `supplier.id === position.supplier.id`, а как сразу в option добавить если условие не совпадает то выбрать пустое значение с value null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на пример [тут](https://renatello.com/default-select-value-vue-js/)

```
<select @change="changeSupplier($event)">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
    <option
     v-for="supplier in suppliers"
     :value="supplier.id"
     :selected="supplier.id === position.supplier.id">{{ supplier.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Только единственное что нужно, так это в <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option> так же ввести v-for="supplier in suppliers"

Comment: @Федотов думаю так имели ввиду

Comment: К сожалению это не работает, если supplier.id не равен position.supplier.id, то опциях выходит только Choose и все

Comment: А так проверьте?